# PDU SMS message not receiving

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, pdu

I am using wavecom gsm modem and implemented the logic to send sms in pdu mode.
But for some operators I am getting : +CMGS response but not receiving the message. And with few more operators like idea, airtel, vodafone etc, with few SIMs I am getting +CMS ERROR : 38, i.e., Network out of order and few with proper response but not receiving SMS.

Has anyone faced these kind of problem? And Can anyone help am I missing something?

Is it the network operator issue?

And I also tested with Quectel modem, but the same result.

Regards,
Sowmya

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the message using a terminal. Use the AT Commands to configure in PDU mode and send a text message through terminal. Most probably, you might have missed some endline characters or something. However, if you are getting CMS error than there must be something wrong with your network registration.
Please feel free to ask more about the issue. Thanks